# Null Pointer When Extending Android's Application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context, applicationcontext

I've been experimenting with extending Application as a quick way of getting hold of the Application Context object. I have a class like so:

```
public class PageMonitorApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext()
    {
        return super.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

And my manifest includes:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".PageMonitorApplication">
```

However, when creating an instance of `PageMonitorActivity` and calling `getApplicationContext()` I get a null pointer exception. Whilst debugging in eclipse and inspecting the instance of `PageMonitorActivity`, I can see that `base=null`.

Can anyone advise what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super.getApplicationContext()` is returning `null` because `PageMonitorApplication` *is* the application context. You should check if `getApplicationContext` returns `null`, and if so, just use the `Context` you already have.

To get a reference to `PageMonitorApplication`, call `getApplicationContext` on the current `Activity` or `Service` (or other `Context` you may have).

Comment: I'm not getting this... so in getApplicationContext() I could just return _this_?

Comment: No, the point is that `PageMonitorApplication` _is_ the application context. You don't need that method at all.

Comment: But if I call a Context method on an instance of PageMonitorApplication, I get a null pointer. E.g. Context context = new PageMonitorApplication(); context.getDatabasePath("my_db"); causes a null pointer.

Comment: When you say "an instance of PageMonitorApplication," do you mean that somewhere in your application, you are explicitly creating an instance of it (`new PageMonitorApplication()`)? You should _never_ do that. You should always call `getApplicationContext` on the current `Activity` or `Service` to get a reference to it. Creating it yourself will not initialize it properly.

Comment: In that case then, I've got the wrong end of the stick. I wanted a way to get an ApplicationContext from anywhere in my app without passing a Context around as a parameter. So PageMonitorApplication was meant to be a way of doing that - create an instance of it and you could get the required Context from it. But I still need a Context to get hold of a PageMonitorApplication then I'm no better off.

Comment: If you really want this behavior, just add a static method to your PageMonitorApplication that returns an instance of PageMonitorApplication that you set in the onCreate method to `this`. That will give you an easy way to get the ApplicationContext from anywhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks Brigham, that's what I've ended up doing. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside any activity you can directly access the **ApllicationContext** object using **getApplicationContext()**.No need to create and experiment using Application class.

Comment: I wanted to make it easy to access the ApplicationContext **outside** of an Activity.

Comment: what would you like to do with the ApplicationContext outside the activity?

Comment: @JosephusVillarey Even if he needs outside he can send getApplicationContext() as argument and recieve it wherever he wants as Context parameter.Isn't it ?

Comment: I was experimenting with ways of getting the applicationcontext without passing a Context parameter.

Comment: @JosephusVillarey It's theoretical really, but if I want to put something in the apps file storage area, I'd need a context and this acticity need not be in an Activity.

Comment: Why u want that if u can get it more easily ?

Comment: To learn more about Android - like I said, I'm just experimenting.